# In Journey builder Total Entries count is different from total population

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

[image]

Why in journey builder,  total population (3381) is less than the people entered (3408) the journey.

What causes the drop of people and how could it be rectified?

Answer (score 0):

This drop in population can occur due to following reasons:

1) You might have configured a filter in your entry source which is filtering contacts after they have attempted to enter in the journey.

2) I have seen many times that the number shown is not accurate. To get the actual number of contacts that entered the journey and received the first email, please create a report and verify.

3) You might have used a sendError function in your email with a condition that restricts the email to be sent to those contacts who do not pass the condition.

4) The data extension that you have configured as an entry source might not have any value in the email column.